# How to join result of a Group by Query to another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following `Group By` SQL:

```
SELECT
 s.Login_Name, COUNT(s.s1CIDNumber)
  FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s
  group by s.Login_Name
```

I want to know how I can join this result set to another table(`tblUsers`) to add user_id to the result set (`tblSurvey` and `tblUsers` have 1-1 relationship on Login_Name)

I tried the following:

```
Select  u.User_Id from tblUsers u,a.Login_Name
inner join
(SELECT
 s.Login_Name Login_Name, COUNT(s.s1CIDNumber)as abc
  FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s
  group by s.Login_Name) a

 on 
 u.Login_Name=a.Login_Name
```

I get errors. The problem is columns of **`a`** are not visible outside.

For example `a.abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake here `from tblUsers u,a.Login_Name` try to move this piece of code `a.Login_Name` to select

```
Select  u.User_Id, a.Login_Name from tblUsers u
inner join
(SELECT
 s.Login_Name Login_Name, COUNT(s.s1CIDNumber)as abc
  FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s
  group by s.Login_Name) a

 on 
 u.Login_Name=a.Login_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `from` clause is in the wrong place:

```
Select  u.User_Id, a.*
from tblUsers u inner join
     (SELECT s.Login_Name, COUNT(s.s1CIDNumber) as abc
      FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s
      GROUP BY s.Login_Name
     ) a
     ON u.Login_Name = a.Login_Name;
```



Answer (score 0):

The from should reference a table not a column:

```
Select  u.User_Id, a.Login_Name from tblUsers u
inner join
```

Other than that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this should do it.

```
select
    s.Login_Name, 
    u.col_a,
    u.col_b,
    u.col_c,
    count(s.s1CIDNumber)
from 
    [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey] s
    join tblUsers t on s.user_id = t.user_id
group by 
    s.Login_Name
    u.col_a,
    u.col_b,
    u.col_c
```